# Bing Map control not displaying map

Tags: c#, windows-runtime, bing-maps, windows-8.1-universal

In my Windows 8.1 Application, I tried to integrate Bing Map control and provided my Map key but when I am running the application it's just showing blocked icon/black screen.
Event I tried downloading Bing Maps sample from [MSDN](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/Using-Bing-Maps-in-1f2286fe/file/117295/4/Using%20Bing%20Maps%20in%20Universal%20Apps.zip), but in that also I am getting the same error after provding bing map key. So I am not sure what's the actual issue, is issue with my bing map key?
Here's the screenshot of how I created my Key from Bing Map portal:

[image]

And below is the screenshot that I see on screen when I run my application:

[image]

Bing Map Block Error:

[image]

Comment: What country are you located in? Try updating your video drivers. Try looking at network traffic with Fiddler and see if the tile requests are being blocked by a firewall.

Comment: Thnx for your reply, for somehow I am not able to debug trough fidder, but today I am getting blocked icon on the map,I added screenshot of that in my post. I am trying to access this from India.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, there are certain countries in which the Windows 8.1 map control is disabled as documented here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj670541.aspx You can get around this by setting the HomeRegion property of the map to a country that isn't blocked. For example HomeRegion="US"